# How can I animate/manipulate position of UIViews laid out with Storyboards before they render onscreen?

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I'm working with a designer to build a simple game for iOS. We've been using storyboards to build the menu scenes.

We have custom view objects, which are composed of multiple subviews (multiple buttons, labels, etc.), which we'd like to animate/slide onscreen after the associated view controller has loaded.

How can I animate the position of these views, which have been built with Storyboards? I can't seem to figure out where in the ViewController lifecycle to implement the animation, as the x/y position specified in the storyboard always seems to override the animation I implement in viewDidLoad, or viewDidAppear, etc.

In a perfect world, my designer would be able to place the view in the desired 'target' position in the storyboard, and I'd then reposition it offscreen in code, and animate it onscreen back to the target position. That'd be easiest from a workflow perspective.

But we'd also settle for positioning the view offscreen on the storyboards, and then simply sliding it onscreen after the page has loaded. So for example, assuming that on the storyboard, **viewIWantToAnimate** has an initial frame position of (0, -100). And I want to slide it down to (0,0)...

Is there a simple way to do something like:

```
@interface MyGameViewController : UIViewController
{
  __weak IBOutlet UIView *viewIWantToAnimate;
}

@implementation MyGameViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                   animations:^{
                    CGRect onScreenFrame = CGRectMake(0,0, viewIWantToAnimate.frame.size.width, viewIWantToAnimate.frame.size.height )
                     viewIwantToAnimate.frame = onScreenFrame;
                   }];
}
@end
```

Comment: there is viewWillApear, but more precise is viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Looks like viewDidLayoutSubviews is being called multiple times -- only want the animation to occur once. My hunch is this isn't the right place to trigger the animation, no?

Comment: normally I would do the position setup in viewwillapear, and the animation itself in viewdidapear. or you can do your setup just before the animated block

Comment: I agree, that would make sense, but the problem I'm having is that my attempts to reposition in viewDidAppear, are being ignored. The position specified in the storyboard seems to overrule viewWillAppear. Likewise, any animation in viewDidAppear is being ignored.

Comment: so if you add  topButtonPanel.frame = CGRectMake(0,-100, viewIWantToAnimate.frame.size.width, viewIWantToAnimate.frame.size.height ) just before the animatewithduration line, nothing will happen?

Comment: very strange. if I add that line, just before the animation, in viewDidAppear, there's a flicker. The view starts at (0,0), where it's been positioned, the moves offscreen, then animates down. If I move that line of code to viewWillAppear, there's no animation... the view stays at (0,0). If I instead move the view up to (0,-100) or something on the storyboard, it never slides down. Wondering if placing the view offscreen on the storyboard extends/distorts the frame coordinate system...